# Check_MK: How to add service to Servicegroup?

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring, check-mk

I'm new at monitoring, and would to know is it possible to add a Services to a Servicegroup.

What I will do:

I have Servers how i monitor and created a Servicegroup, and now I will add queries like storage alert add to all Servers in this Servicegroup.

Is there a way to realize this?

My Software:

Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Check_MK RAW, 1.6.0p6 (OpenSource Version)

Comment: A host group can only contains hosts - I think you would need a Service Group?

Comment: Oh, I'm not knowed, I edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service and Host Groups are both assigned through a ruleset.

First you have to create the Service Group: in the "WATO Configuration" menu go to "Host & Service Groups", then select "Service Groups" and create the group you need.

To assign services, go to "Host & Service Parameters", "Grouping", "Assignment of services to service groups" and create a new rule. Here you can select the Service Group you just created and set specific host or service names that should be added to the group.